# MAPI Outlook object model Mailitem.senton > Mailitem.receivedtime, how is this possible?

Tags: vba, outlook, mapi

I have been trying to figure this out as I am working on a deliverable for which I need to provide metadata for emails. As the title suggests when I am recording this metadata often the MailItem.Senton property will be greater than the MailItem.ReceivedTime property. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that these values come from different places - the Date MIME header is created by the sender, while the received time is based on the receiving machine time.

Comment: I figured as much, and was hoping you would chime in here. Is there a way I can get an accurate pair of sent/receive dates on one machine or is that not possible?

Comment: No, you should never depend on any dates or their relationship to any other dates.